# How to match any content between two strings?

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to match anything that is contained within two string as follows:

```
teststring = %-12x (my value)
```

Pattern:

```
%-(.*?)x (my value)
```

Result should be:

```
12
```

But the regex does not work. Why?

Comment: `my` vs `may` and escaped `(` and `)`.

Comment: Use https://regex101.com/ for testing.

Comment: "contained within two string" Which strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your regex (my instead of may) and you need to escape the `()`:

```
String s = "%-12x (may value)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("%-(.*?)x \\(may value\\)").matcher(s);
if (m.find() && m.groupCount() >= 1) System.out.println(m.group(1)); //12
```

Comment: Thanks that works, apart that if there are several start strings like `%- %- %-12x` I'd like to match only from the latest `%-`. But currently it finds the first one..

Comment: How about: `m.group(m.groupCount())`?

Comment: Thanks. Would it be also possible to replace the found group only (the digit)? `pattern.matcher(s).replaceAll("100");` would replace the full content `%-12x (my value)`, not only the digit.

Comment: @membersound I'm not sure

Answer (score 1):

The regex does not work because `(` and `)` are metacharacters that need to be escaped:

```
%-(.*?)x [(]my value[)]
```

Without `[]` or `\` the engine treats them as markers for the second capturing group, which always "captures" `"my value"` upon successful match.

If you would like to make a regular expression suitable for `replaceAll`, remove the capturing group, and use `%-` and `x [(]my value[)]` as part of a lookahead and lookbehind:

```
String s = "%-12x (my value)";
String r = s.replaceAll("(?<=%-).*?(?=x [(]my value[)])", "quick brown fo");
System.out.println(r); // prints "%-quick brown fox (my value)"
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/zWpuZd)

Comment: Thanks, that works, appart from the fact that it founds the full content as a match, not only the number `12`,

Comment: @membersound You have to extract the capture group.

Comment: @membersound Get the first [capturing group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group()) to pull `12` out of the match by calling `match.group(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the '?' is not needed since with '*' you are telling there must be zero or more of any character.

Should be something like this `%-(.*)x`.